# declaring a Tuple of KeyValuePair in C#

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, keyvaluepair

For the sake of my code I need a tuple which has 2 components both of which are KeyValuePairs. However, for the life of me I can't even figure out how to declare this thing. I had it working with normal strings

```
Tuple<string, string> t = new Tuple<string, string>("abc", "123");
```

But I need to have KeyValue Pairs instead of strings, I've tried something like this but it refuses to compile saying that constructor can't take 2 arguments.

```
Tuple<KeyValuePair<string, string>, KeyValuePair<string,string>> a = 
    new Tuple<KeyValuePair<string, string> ("a", "1"), 
    KeyValuePair<string, string> ("b", "2");
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Please feel free to use this if it helps you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y2rTlM

Comment: Have you considered using a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead? It's basically a collection of `KeyValuePair` objects that have unique keys. `var a = new Dictionary<string, string> { {"a", "1"}, {"b", "2"} };`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Tuple<KeyValuePair<string, string>, KeyValuePair<string, string>> a =
        new Tuple<KeyValuePair<string, string>, KeyValuePair<string, string>>(
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "1"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b", "2")
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, a bit shorter:

```
using KVPS = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>;

namespace Test 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tuple<KVPS, KVPS> a =
                Tuple.Create(
                    new KVPS("a", "1"),
                    new KVPS("b", "2")
                    );
            Console.WriteLine($"{a.Item1.Key} {a.Item1.Value} : {a.Item2.Key} {a.Item2.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

This might be useful if you have a lots of tuples of tuples and similar.